Module Class doesn't add the class to the site module
Nothing is happening when I modify the Module Class value in a custom side module:

Not sure why it matters, but Module Style is left at default value:

I tried both with and without a space before the class, also with and without a dot. How is that field supposed to be filled to add h-100 CSS class to <div class="custom">?
Note: I don't want any extra HTML except the added class to the single extra div that the module uses. Anything else should stay as is.

Did you set the Module Style (bottom option in the advanced tab)?

@GlennArkell nope

Try changing that setting from inherited to all the others in turn and check to see when your class shows up. I occasionally change it to HTML5 or none depending on what I want it to do.

That only added some random classes and other stuff to the HTML, like the title of the site module. The class that I need wasn't there with any of the options.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with this custom module, however, as a test I created a simple custom module with some text as the content.  I set the module class in the advanced tab to read " h-100" (with a space to separate it from any other class) and set the module style = "html5" and resulting code is as follows:
<div class="grid-child container-sidebar-right">
    <div class="moduletable  h-100">
        <h3>Test Custom Module</h3>        
        <div id="mod-custom194" class="mod-custom custom">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. A laudantium rerum ad aliquam excepturi aut nisi magnam. Est rerum quia non harum accusamus sit architecto dolorem sed quod nihil qui ullam maxime sed sint reiciendis sit architecto minus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

I hope this helps.

Unfortunately, like I mentioned, this doesn't do anything in my case. Only the table one adds the class, but also some extra random HTML and styling I don't want. All I need is the class on the single extra div, that's it. I'd guess a solution would be to define some new styling that just applies the module class, no idea how to do that though and not worth my time to check it.
